# In a Rails routes.rb file, what's the difference between [ Rails.application.routes.draw do ] and [ <ApplicationName>::Application.routes.draw do ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I create Rails applications, my config/routes.rb always begins

```
ApplicationName::Application.routes.draw do
```

But I've also seen

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
```

What's the difference and how does each syntax get generated? Does the alternate syntax affect the application in any significant way? Am I even asking the right questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more recent versions of rails (3.0 and above, I think, based on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html) support the newer syntax `Rails.application`, while earlier versions used `AppName::Application` - the older format may still be supported, but if you are using rails 3 or greater, just use the `Rails.application` variant. In rails 4.1.x, the generated routes.rb in a rails app uses the newer format.